# How to fix Conda "missing path to environment variable"?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, conda

I have a conda environment named `tensorflow_p36`. When I run `import mujoco-py` I get the following error:

> Exception:  Missing path to your environment variable.
>
> Please add following line to .bashrc:
>        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin

Therefore, I add the line above to .bashrc:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX:~$ echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

and

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX:~$ source ~/.bashrc
```

This however does not add the environment variable to the conda environmnet. Such that when I run

```
ubuntu@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I get:

> :/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin

but when I run from inside the virtual env

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I don't get the exported path showing. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

---

**What I've tried**

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598963/how-to-set-specific-environment-variables-when-activating-conda-environment):

```
cd $CONDA_PREFIX
mkdir -p ./etc/conda/activate.d
mkdir -p ./etc/conda/deactivate.d
touch ./etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
touch ./etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh
```

I edited the env_vars.sh to include

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin
```

Now when I run `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from inside the virtual env

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I get `/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin`

but the exception remains:

> Exception:
>       Missing path to your environment variable.
>       Current values LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
>       Please add following line to .bashrc:
>       export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but solved it by launching the IDE (PyCharm community in my case) from terminal via `pycharm-communinity`.
I found this solutions in this [GitHub Issue comment](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/issues/267#issuecomment-441556633).